# Unable to use Nvidia OpenCL in Singularity containers

Tags: opencl, nvidia, singularity-container

I'm struggling a lot with making OpenCL GPU acceleration available within a Singularity container. Executed directly on the host itself (without Singularity in between), I get the GPU application, a proprietary molecular modelling/simulation software called Yasara, running on Linux Mint 20.1 (Kernel 5.4.0-91-generic) with Nvidia driver 530.41 and CUDA version 12.1. And `clinfo` gives me lots of output, but interestingly, without the ICD lines at the end. However, there's a note saying: "NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 2.2".

Now, this happens when I call `clinfo` within the container executed with the `--nv` flag:

```
$ singularity exec --nv image.sif /bin/bash
Singularity> clinfo
Number of platforms          0
```

which looks better when binding an additional directory pointing to ICD libraries

```
$ singularity exec --nv --bind /etc/OpenCL image.sif /bin/bash
Singularity> ls /etc/OpenCL/vendors/
nvidia.icd
cat /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd 
libnvidia-opencl.so.1
Singularity> clinfo
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
  Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 12.1.98
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE

[... much more stuff ...]

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.11
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.1
    NOTE:   your OpenCL library only supports OpenCL 2.1,
        but some installed platforms support OpenCL 3.0.
        Programs using 3.0 features may crash
        or behave unexpectedly
```

Obviously, this time (in the container) I see ICD output at the end. The only file in `/etc/OpenCl`, nvidia.icd, lists a library called `libnvidia-opencl.so.1` which is associated with the current Nvidia driver 530.41

```
$ locate libnvidia-opencl.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.530.41.03
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.530.41.03
```

So things are apparently looking fine, but when I run Yasara within Singularity, it gives me an error and does not utilize the GPU:

```
OpenCL program build failed with error -11 (CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE):
Device     NVIDIA Corporation NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 (version 3.00 (OpenCL 3.0 CUDA)) with driver 530.41.03
```

And indeed it is a little confusing to see different `clinfo` outputs on the host vs. in the container. In particular, the OpenCL version 2.1 differs from 2.2 shown on the host.

The reason might be that I recently replaced Nvidia driver 470 with the 530 version (along with the latest CUDA toolkit). Maybe, two different installations/configurations are competing. Because when I pass the current Cuda libraries to the container `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, i get the same clinfo output as on the host (no ICD lines at the end and OpenCL 2.2 supported). However, the runtime error `CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE` remains.

Is anyone able to tell me what I need to change in order to get the OpenCL application running in singularity?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have the OpenCL source code I suggest you look for the macro CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION to see what version it is trying to use. It is set to 100x the actual version number, so 3.0 -> 300, 2.2 -> 220 etc. If it worked on 2.2, but not on 2.1, then you might find you can just change the 220 to 210, but there's no guarantee. It's weird that you're getting a different version in the container. Maybe the container only supports up to version 2.1?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @SimonGoater. Unfortunately I have no experience at all with OpenCL development and how to apply that suggestion. I'm still hoping that someone knows an "easy" way of repairing the situation

Comment: Maybe you could just ensure you're using the latest version of the container then....

Comment: It's already the latest available Singularity version. However, today I found multiple instances of several identically named header files related to OpenCL on my system. For instance opencl.h exists in /usr/include/CL/ (most likely installed as a dependency of other repository packages) as well as in /usr/local/cuda-12.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include/ which I had installed few days back. This probably causes the problem. I will play around tomorrow with passing the one or other path to container variables CPATH/C_INCLUDE_PATH/CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH or something.

Comment: @SimonGoater i now used an example opencl code and printed CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION. and surprisingly it does neither show 220 nor 210, but 300. but how does that relate to the final notes of clinfo where either 2.2 or 2.1 is listed? while clinfo shows 2.2 and running my first CL program, clBuildProgram failes with error code -11 and the build log of clGetProgramBuildInfo is empty :/

Comment: sorry: depending on whether CL.h of /usr/include or /usr/local/cuda/include is used, I get version 220 or 300. but in any case, on the host, the little programm succeeds, in the container it fails with error code -11

Comment: @SimonGoater i finally succeded with singularity/OpenCL by ignoring the cuda-12.1 version but setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the opencl 2.2 installation of the standard path. so many thanks for your hint. that helped me